# How much nfts can be transferd on 1 smart contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I can't figure out if i need to Deploy a smart contract for each transfer? or can 1 smart contract serve several transactions? Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to deploy another smart contract to transfer NFTs.

Info about each token ownership is stored in its collection contract. So you just need to execute the `safeTransferFrom()` function on the collection contract from the current owner address, passing it following params:

1. current owner (`_from`)
2. receiver (`_to`)
3. token ID (`_tokenId`)

There are several ways to execute the function from a regular (non-contract) address, for example using the UI of EtherScan/BSCScan under the `Contract` -> `Write Contract` section on the detail page of the collection contract address.

Note: All assuming the collection contract follows the [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me a lot, but i do need to deploy a contract if i want to use the safeTransferFrom(). otherwise where will i call it from. ps i am using solidity and truffle

Comment: @ilayTertman You don't need to deploy a contract for that. One of the ways to call the function is to use the EtherScan/BSCScan UI described in my answer. You'll need to connect your wallet (e.g. MetaMask or TrustWallet) with the site... Also, I haven't tested it but I think that MetaMask is able to send NFTs as well using their UI if you hold the tokens on the MM address. (which should invoke the `safeTransferFrom()` function in the background)